# GoogleDrive API - how to get folder hierarchy from file in python

Tags: google-drive-api

I using the following code to get all the files in my drive

```
files_list = service_v3.files().list(corpora='drive',
                                     supportsAllDrives=True,
                                     includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                     driveId=drive['id'],
                                     spaces='drive',
                                     fields='*').execute()
```

Now in each file I have a parent:

```
files_list[0]['parents']
```

How can I get data about this parent?

I've tried to use

```
service_v2.parents().list(fileId='xxx')
```

but it does not return much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to implement three steps:

1. List all files of interest - as you are already doing with `files_list = service_v3.files().list`
2. Loop through the list results or pick a certain file (as you are doing with `files_list[0]`) and retrieve its parents (as you are doing), e.g. `parent = files_list[0].get('parents')`
3. Use the method `service_v3.files().get(fileId=parents[0], fields="*").execute()` to retrieve the information about the parent by its Id

I recommend you to use the Try It API of the [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221K81_0NBgv4mICTLS4jFNYLSVTDtdtJyRZr8jgrJfg5k%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22fields%22%3A%22parents%22%7D) methods in order to get a better understanding of the results those methods give you.

Also, please note that `service_v2.parents().list(fileId='xxx')` is using the old version of the Drive API (v2), and in any case - if you want to retrieve a file with a specified ID, the correct method to do it is `get`opposed to `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Actually I've noticed that `files.list()` method return the folders and the files in a single list and you can differentiate then by looking at `mimeType` (in folder the `mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder`)

Comment: Yes, you can indeed. When you list your results you can implement the search query `q` to list only the file of the desired mimeType.